# Javascript function call stack for the below code

Tags: javascript

```js
(function timer() {
  for (var i = 0; i <= 5; i++) {
    (function () {
      setTimeout(function clog() {
        console.log(i);
      }, i * 1000);
    })();
  }
})();
```

This is the output-

```
6
6
6
6
6
6
```

how is the IIFs getting loaded on the stack? are all of them pushed and then processed and popped one by one to get the i = 6?
And the output does wait for 1 sec while printing 6.

Comment: Haven't you used your debugger to see for yourself?

Comment: `setTimeout()` callbacks are not on the stack. They're in a queue managed by the runtime. Other than the callback when the timer fires, the stack is essentially empty.

Comment: The explanation of this behavior is very well covered at [JavaScript closure inside loops – simple practical example](/q/750486/4642212).

Answer (score 3):

`var` will make it a global variable,in order to make it work as you expected,need to change

```
var i = 0; i <= 5; i++
```

to

```
let i = 0; i <= 5; i++
```

```js
(function timer() {
  for (let i = 0; i <= 5; i++) {
    (function () {
      setTimeout(function clog() {
        console.log(i);
      }, i * 1000);
    })();
  }
})();
```

Comment: To elaborate on this a bit: `var i` gets scoped to the function (timer), not the loop. So each timeout callback is using the same `i`, and by the time your first console.log runs the loop is finished and i's value is 6